# RegEx for Ignoring Special Characters in substring search

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an HTML table with a search box when finding an exact match it will surround the value with span tag so I can highlight it with CSS. The issue I am having is trying to implement RegExp method that will find a substring while ignoring special characters.

**Working code**

this.tableSearch is the search box string value

value = is the data point string in table cell

```
    if (this.tableSearch != "") {
        const regexSearch = new RegExp('(' + this.tableSearch + ')', 'ig');
        value = value && value.replace(regexSearch, '<span class="table-data-found">$1</span>');
    }
```

**ie. this.tableSearch = “821”**

(405) 821-7615

(817) 240-7821

**This is where it gets challenging for me.** Some use cases that the RegExp method needs to find and add span tag

"8-21" ignoring the dash "-"

(512) 248-2144

AND also find "8) 21" ignoring the paren and space ") "

(818) 217-2144

This RegExp method would also apply to other types of data like addresses

**ie. this.tableSearch = "19803 E 38TH ST"**

Find an address ignoring "."

19803 E. 38TH ST

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Why does the same method have to handle phone numbers and addresses? It seems like it would be a bit easier if you handled each separately.

Comment: @isaactfa I would like for the RegExp to be generic enough to handle (ignore) all special characters not case-by-case.  If you have a solution to handle separately I would love to take a look at it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am sure that there is better way to do it but you would basically want to say that there is some set of characters that you will allow in-between your search terms. In this case it looks like you are wanting to exclude (space), `-`(hyphen), `.`(period), `(`(left paren), and `)`(right paren).

So if you were to split your search term with an allow of 0 to more items from the excluded list, then you should be able to find the string that you want.

E.g.

```
var tableSearch = "821";
var phone1 = "(405) 821-7615";
var phone2 = "(817) 240-7821";

var data = [];
data.push(phone1);
data.push(phone2);

var regex = '[.\ -]*';
var searchTerm = tableSearch.split("").join(regex);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var matches = data[i].match(searchTerm);
    console.log(matches);
}
```

Which when ran produces:

```
[ '821', index: 6, input: '(405) 821-7615', groups: undefined ]
[ '821', index: 11, input: '(817) 240-7821', groups: undefined ]
```

Using `*` is saying "match 0 to one or more". You could replace `*` with `?` to only match 0 or 1. But that wouldn't work in the case where the string has more than 1 exclusion.

I've found that https://regex101.com/ is a good site to do regex tests to figure it all out.