# Find sentence in base string considering only letters and numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find a sentence, which looks similar to this:

`I'm a sentence with some text and number and so on 45`

In a base string that can look like this, like markdown text:

`Here is some content \n \n > Listing some items: - Hello, I'm *** bold ***. \n \n I'm a \n 
\n sentence with - some text and    number and so on 45`

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55907086/regex-for-ignoring-special-characters-in-substring-search) question that uses Regex but I cant get it to work in my example. I've also changed a bit like this but no success:

```
const content = "Here is some content \n \n > Listing some items: - Hello, I'm *** bold ***. \n \n I'm a \n \n sentence with - some text and    number and so on 45"


const search = "I'm a sentence with some text and number and so on 45"

const regex = '[^a-zA-Z0-9]*?';
const searchTerm = search.split("").join(regex);

var matches = content.match(searchTerm);
console.log(matches);
```

I've tried different regex variables like: '[^a-zA-Z0-9]*?', '[^\w\d\s]', and '[.\ -]*'

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should provide more information. To get from the "like markdown" line to the "sentence" you want to find, not only do you have to remove some special characters, like `>`, but also some special characters together with ordinary character they are prepended to because they are special together, like `\n`; furthermore you have collapsed consecutive spaces to one space only (and space is not special); you've also removed some actual text, like `Here is some content`; finally, what if the line you want to extract contains something like `In MATLAB I can write n/3 as 3\n; x^2 + 1 > 0`?

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is create a clean version of the string you're searching within, by stripping out unwanted characters (I'm leaving in the single quote, since you're matching on "I'm"). Then you can do a simple string search against the cleaned up content.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/edlucas/pen/eYNdXLq

```js
const content = "Here is some content \n \n > Listing some items: - Hello, I'm *** bold ***. \n \n I'm a \n \n sentence with - some text and    number and so on 45";

const search = "I'm a sentence with some text and number and so on 45";

// Remove the unwanted characters and then all multiple spaces
newContent = content.replace(/[^\w' ]/g, '').replace(/[\s]+/g,' ');

console.log(newContent);

const matches = newContent.includes(search);

console.log('Matches?', matches);
```

Comment: Hi Ed. Thanks for your reply. The thing is I want to know the exact index where my search sentence starts in the string I'm searching within.